# Model with supposed high accuracy predicts poorly on real images

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, image-recognition, tf.keras, multiclass-classification

Originally, I was experimenting using `tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist`, but I also experienced this pitfall with a subset of [Joost Hazelzet's Images of LEGO Bricks](https://www.kaggle.com/joosthazelzet/lego-brick-images).

I'm, splitting the dataset into 3 parts: *train*, *val* and *test*.
After fitting a model to *train* and *val*, the evaluation on *test* gives high accuracy — i.e. typically over 85%.
However, when confronted with real-life images, the model yields poorer predictions — around 50% accuracy.

Complexifying the models — i.e. stuffing more densely connected and convolutional neurons in, and sprinkling drop-outs around — and empirically using different optimizers improved the results.

Still, what I'm struggling to understand is the origin of the **gap between accuracy on evaluation data and accuracy on real-life data**. I would have expected the evaluation results to be solid since the *test* data is supposed to be completely unknown... Now, it's not always possible to come up with extra data for an additional *"this-time-it's-the-real-one"* evaluation in order to get more realistic model scorings...

Does the phenomenon have a name?
What could it be due to?
Are my own MNIST-alike digit drawings so different from the training data that the computer is confused — I've heard computers don't see the same way as us?
Is it a case of overfitting that I'm not experienced enough to spot?

---

Below is the code I used to train the models on MNIST.
Imports not included for brevity.

```py
( x_train, y_train ), ( x_test, y_test ) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    test_size = 10000 / 60000)
```

At this point, the dataset is normalized with values between `0.0` and `1.0`, and split in 3:

```
| Part      |  .dtype   |  .shape       |
| ---------:|:--------- |:------------- |
|  x_train  |  float64  | (50k, 28, 28) |
|  y_train  |  uint8    | (50k, )       |
|  x_val    |  float64  | (10k, 28, 28) |
|  y_val    |  uint8    | (10k, )       |
|  x_test   |  float64  | (10k, 28, 28) |
|  y_test   |  uint8    | (10k, )       |
```

Sample pick just to prove myself it's randomized:

[image: A dozen digits from the MNIST dataset.]

Here is how I'm building and training my models:

```py
model = Sequential([
    Input(( 28, 28 )),

    # Reshape(( 28, 28, 1 )),

    # Conv2D(32,
    #     kernel_size = ( 3, 3 ),
    #     strides = ( 1, 1 ),
    #     activation = relu,
    #     kernel_initializer = HeNormal()),
    # Conv2D(32,
    #     kernel_size = ( 3, 3 ),
    #     strides = ( 1, 1 ),
    #     activation = relu,
    #     kernel_initializer = HeNormal()),
    # MaxPooling2D(( 2, 2 )),
    # SpatialDropout2D(0.30),

    # Conv2D(64,
    #     kernel_size = ( 3, 3 ),
    #     strides = ( 1, 1 ),
    #     activation = relu,
    #     kernel_initializer = HeNormal()),
    # Conv2D(64,
    #     kernel_size = ( 3, 3 ),
    #     strides = ( 1, 1 ),
    #     activation = relu,
    #     kernel_initializer = HeNormal()),
    # MaxPooling2D(( 2, 2 )),
    # SpatialDropout2D(0.30),

    Flatten(),

    # Dense(128,
    #     activation = relu,
    #     kernel_initializer = HeNormal()),
    # Dropout(0.30),

    # Dense(128,
    #     activation = relu,
    #     kernel_initializer = HeNormal()),
    # Dropout(0.30),

    Dense(10,
        activation = softmax,
        kernel_initializer = HeNormal())
])

model.compile(
    optimizer = Adam(1 / 1000),
    loss = SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = False),
    metrics = [ SparseCategoricalAccuracy() ])

fitting = model.fit(
    x_train, y_train,
    validation_data = ( x_val, y_val ),
    batch_size = 128,
    epochs = 10,
    verbose = 0)

accuracy = model.evaluate(
    x_test, y_test,
    batch_size = 128,
    verbose = 0)[1]
```

Here, `accuracy = model.evaluate(...)` is supposed to be 92.54%.
Below is the plotting of `fitting = model.fit(...)`:

[image: Model training and validation accuracy over epochs.]

The fitting plots of larger `Dropout`-full models don't even show the symptoms of overfitting — which, to me, boil down to "*train curve above val curve ⇒ overfitting*".

I also drew some digits using GIMP, my computer mouse, and my terrible writing:

[image: My own digits.]

And I tried to make predictions on them:

```py
x_drawing = Image.open(".../drawing-digits.png")
x_drawing = x_drawing.convert("L")
x_drawing = x_drawing.resize(( 28 * 12, 28))
x_drawing = ImageOps.invert(x_drawing) # Black/White => White/Black
x_drawing = np.asarray(x_drawing)
x_drawing = np.hsplit(x_drawing, 12) # Big image => 1 image/digit
x_drawing = np.array(x_drawing) # List<Array> => Array
x_drawing = x_drawing / 255.0 # 0-255 => 0-1

y_drawing = np.array([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2 ])
y_pred = model.predict(x_drawing)
```

Below are the model's predictions; accuracy on my drawings is now 58.33%, far from the 92% I had before:

[image: Model predictions over my digits.]

---

Below are the outputs of `model.summary()` for 3 configurations.

1. The simplest possible: all layers commented above stay commented.

```
Model: "sequential_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #  
=================================================================
flatten_17 (Flatten)         (None, 784)               0        
_________________________________________________________________
image_label_probabilities (D (None, 8)                 6280     
=================================================================
Total params: 6,280
Trainable params: 6,280
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

2. Adding in the `Dense` layers.

```
Model: "sequential_18"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #  
=================================================================
flatten_18 (Flatten)         (None, 784)               0        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 128)               100480    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 128)               16512    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0        
_________________________________________________________________
image_label_probabilities (D (None, 8)                 1032     
=================================================================
Total params: 118,024
Trainable params: 118,024
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

3. Adding in the convolutions.

```
Model: "sequential_19"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #  
=================================================================
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 28, 28, 1)         0        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_30 (Conv2D)           (None, 26, 26, 32)        320      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_31 (Conv2D)           (None, 24, 24, 32)        9248     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_19 (MaxPooling (None, 12, 12, 32)        0        
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout2d_19 (Spatia (None, 12, 12, 32)        0        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_32 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 10, 64)        18496    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_33 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 64)          36928    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPooling (None, 4, 4, 64)          0        
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout2d_20 (Spatia (None, 4, 4, 64)          0        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_19 (Flatten)         (None, 1024)              0        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 128)               131200   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 128)               16512    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_21 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0        
_________________________________________________________________
image_label_probabilities (D (None, 8)                 1032     
=================================================================
Total params: 213,736
Trainable params: 213,736
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Is the `Dense(10)` the only layer besides your input layer? And could you put the `model.summary()` output in your question to? Thanks

Comment: @MZ Edited. `Dense(10)` is the output — and only — layer of the simplest configuration I tried, which yields 90% _eval-_ / 50% _real-_ accuracy. Two other configurations I've tried consist in enabling successively the other `Dense(128)`, and then the convolutions, which yield better _real_ accuracy, yet still with the dreadful gap.

Comment: The first thing I'd suggest is upping the epochs to something like 100. You might even need to train for thousands of epochs to get good results.

Not sure if it matters as you probably understand your code better than I do but your output layer in the summaries is showing as having 8 classes while your other code suggests 10 classes.

Comment: @MZ There are 10 classes in MNIST, and 8 in my subset of the LEGO bricks. Yeah, I've confused the models... Nothing to worry about though (I guess?): I used the same chaining of convs and denses, and the dreadful gap is present in both.